Xcode error: ‘FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h’ file not found in React Native iOS app
I’m working on a React Native project, and my application runs on IOS when I use npx react-native start from the terminal. However, when I try to build the project in Xcode, I get the following error:
/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/RCTSettingsManager.mm:10:9: fatal error: 'FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h' file not found
#import <FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h>.

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have closely followed the RNfirebase documentation and I believe i have implemented everything.
my podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true


require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Test' do
  config = use_native_modules!


  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  pod 'RevenueCat'
  pod 'RevenueCatUI'

  target 'TestTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end


INFO
System:
OS: macOS 15.0
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
Memory: 98.41 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell:
version: "5.9"
path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node:
version: 22.9.0
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm:
version: 10.8.3
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2024.10.07.00
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.15.2
path: /Users/username/.rbenv/shims/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:
- DriverKit 24.0
- iOS 18.0
- macOS 15.0
- tvOS 18.0
- visionOS 2.0
- watchOS 11.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903
Xcode:
version: 16.0/16A242d
path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java:
version: 17.0.12
path: /usr/bin/javac
Ruby:
version: 2.7.6
path: /Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby
npmPackages:
"@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
react:
installed: 18.3.1
wanted: 18.3.1
react-native:
installed: 0.75.4
wanted: 0.75.4
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
"react-native": Not Found
Android:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
